# jQuery clickable text

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to html/jQuery and I'm trying to figure out how to create clickable text

I have a div with the id 'inputFormBasic' and there are multiple rows with multiple cells and inside those cells are labels.

I want to make these labels clickable. Here is what I've come up with but I don't get any response from the website I'm working on.

```
$('#inputFormBasic').find('label').click(function() {
     alert('You clicked a label!');
 });
```

I've also tried using `label.ui-state-active`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: There is a lot of code, I've included a snippet.

```
<div id="inputFormBasic">
<tr>
    <td style="width:25px" align="left"><label>LABEL 1&nbsp;</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL2&nbsp;</label></td>
</tr>

<tr class="formSpacingRow"></tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL3&nbsp;</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL4&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL5&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL6&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL7&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL8&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL9&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL10&nbsp;</label></td>
</tr>

</div>



<script>

        $('#inputFormBasic').find('label').click(function() {

            alert('you clicked a label');
        });

 </script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? jQuery included? Code running after the DOM is ready? Also, a complete code example in your question would be helpful so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: By clickable, do you mean editable?

Comment: Just to check, have you placed all of this inside a Document ready call? Might be useful to create a quick JS Fiddle.

Comment: at face value, it works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/w8fmhgy5/  so you will need to provide more context to your specific code

Comment: You can simplify it slightly by doing this: `$('#inputFormBasic label')`... https://jsfiddle.net/w8fmhgy5/1/

Comment: Working fine http://jsfiddle.net/0oo84ur4/

Comment: @BeatAlex the `.find` is better for performance as it can do the id bit faster: https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

Comment: Thanks @Pete, I didn't know that! :)

Comment: @Varun no, eventually when I click on a label, a description of it will be provided from a database

Comment: @thecraighammond yes I've tried with and without document ready

Comment: @j08691 I have a 'dialog is not a function' error but it's from a section of code that I didn't write

Comment: OK, well we still need a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you edit your question to include all the relevant code please?

Comment: Your HTML example contains invalid HTML. Plus you should also post your jQuery, showing how it's being loaded and called. Validity aside however, the code works if called properly: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/b6nt23kn/

Comment: i have update my answer , please check and let me know

Comment: Is your jQuery being run at the end of the page, or in the head inside a document.read() call? You can see from my fiddle that the code you posted works.

Comment: @j08691 it's in the head.. and yes I can see that it does work. I guess it's just a problem on my end that I need to figure out. Thanks for your help

Comment: Here is [jsfiddle working example](https://jsfiddle.net/vvp9vsum/1/).

Comment: Since it's in the head, is it within a document.ready() call? It needs to be, otherwise it's running and trying to select elements that don't exist yet. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @j08691 I swear I tried before but adding the document.ready() call worked this time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although your code is working fine. But here are some tips for improvement;

Use [.ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to make sure it initiates after every thing is loaded.

Also you don't need to use [.find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) in your snippet. You can achieve your goal simply using `#inputFormBasic label` as selector.

Something like this;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#inputFormBasic label').click(function() {
      alert('You clicked a label named ' + $(this).html() +'!');
   });
});
```

Also make sure you include your jQuery before this snippet.

Here is [jsfiddle working example](https://jsfiddle.net/vvp9vsum/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this above code

Html Changes

```
<div id="inputFormBasic">
    <table>
<tr>
    <td style="width:25px" align="left"><label>LABEL 1&nbsp;</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL2&nbsp;</label></td>
</tr>

<tr class="formSpacingRow"></tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL3&nbsp;</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL4&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL5&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL6&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL7&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL8&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL9&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label>LABEL10&nbsp;</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
        $('#inputFormBasic').find('table tr:first-child').find("label").click(function () {
            alert('you clicked a label');               
        });
    });
```

[Js Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/8xLattzz/2/)